# Is this a typo about the derived set in textbook Introduction to Set Theory by Hrbacek and Jech?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

In my textbook, $A'$ is the set of all limit points of $A \subseteq \Bbb R$.

> [image]
>
> [image]

I think the below statement is possibly not correct.

> For each $\alpha$, the set $F^{(\alpha)} - F^{(\alpha+1)}$ is the set of ALL isolated points of $F^{(\alpha)}$.

We know that $F^{(\alpha)} \subseteq F$ and $F^{(\alpha)}$ is a closed set for all ordinal $\alpha$. Thus for all $x \notin F$, $x \notin F^{(\alpha)}$ and thus $x$ is an isolated point of $F^{(\alpha)}$. As such, $F^{(\alpha)} - F^{(\alpha+1)}$ is the set of isolated points of $F^{(\alpha)}$, but not ALL.

Please confirm if my observation is correct or not! Thank you for your help!

Comment: The isolated points of $X$ are in particular elements of $X$.

Comment: It's hilarious that I receive a downvote for this question

Comment: I didn't downvote, but don't see why the downvote would be a surprise (or "hilarious"). You keep talking about technical constructions but seem to not understand much more basic concepts.

Comment: Thank you @AndrésE.Caicedo! It's my mistake.

Comment: Down votes are obnoxious swipes, anonymous disapproval without cause, insult without reason, jail without charge. @LeAnhDung

Comment: I agree with you @WilliamElliot. The best bundle for a response is undeniably downvote + comment. But I don't care about downvote anymore. The only thing I care about now is that my questions are carefully written and I am happy with learning math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks right.

It $x\in F^{\alpha}$ is not a limit point,  it's an isolated point (of $F^{\alpha}$).
But $F^{\alpha+1}$ is by definition the derived set of $F^{\alpha}$.  Thus $F^{\alpha}\setminus F^{\alpha+1}$ is $F^{\alpha}$ minus its limit points.  What's left is the isolated points.

As pointed out in the comments,  points outside a set are not considered isolated points (of the set).

Answer (score 1):

For any set $A$, the set $A\setminus A'$ is the set of isolated points of $A$:

$x$ is in $A-A'$ if $x \in A$ and $x \notin A'$ so there exists an open neighbourhood $O$ of $x$ such that $O \cap A \subseteq  \{x\}$ and as we already know $x \in A$, we know that $O \cap A = \{x\}$, i.e. $x$ is an isolated point of $A$. The reverse is obvious: $x$ is an isolated point of $A$ iff $x \in A$ and there is an open set $O$ of $X$ such that $O \cap A= \{x\}$ (i.e. $\{x\}$ is relatively open in $A$), which shows $x \notin A'$ too. So $x \in A-A'$.

The statement in the book is just the special case $A=F^{\alpha)}$ because $A'= F^{(\alpha+1)}$ by the definition.

So no typo, it's completely correct.